# Angular prod build is failing at mini-css-extract-plugin

Tags: angular, handsontable

My Angular 7 application's prod build is failing with the error message:

```
    ERROR in Module build failed (from ./node_modules/mini-css-extract-plugin/dist/loader.js):
TypeError: Cannot read property 'replace' of undefined
    at normalizeBackSlashDirection (D:\WAVZ_1.17.0\Cloud3\resilinc-parent\wavzlite-webapp\node_modules\webpack\lib\RequestShortener.js:16:17)
    at new RequestShortener (D:\WAVZ_1.17.0\Cloud3\resilinc-parent\wavzlite-webapp\node_modules\webpack\lib\RequestShortener.js:26:15)
    at new Compiler (D:\WAVZ_1.17.0\Cloud3\resilinc-parent\wavzlite-webapp\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compiler.js:184:27)
    at Compiler.createChildCompiler (D:\WAVZ_1.17.0\Cloud3\resilinc-parent\wavzlite-webapp\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compiler.js:430:25)
    at Compilation.createChildCompiler (D:\WAVZ_1.17.0\Cloud3\resilinc-parent\wavzlite-webapp\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compilation.js:2481:24)
    at Object.pitch (D:\WAVZ_1.17.0\Cloud3\resilinc-parent\wavzlite-webapp\node_modules\mini-css-extract-plugin\dist\loader.js:70:43)
```

And my suspicion is on

> handsontable

because that is the only dependency that I added in this build.In my package.json these are the handsontable dependencies:

```
"handsontable": "^7.4.2",
"handsontable-pro": "6.2.2",
"@handsontable/angular": "3.0.0",
```

In my local it is working. Command in local is

```
node --max_old_space_size=22000 ./node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng build --watch
```

command in prod is

```
node --max_old_space_size=14336 ./node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng build --prod
```

**Edit**
I have found out what the cause is. Though still do not know the solution. I added "./node_modules/handsontable-pro/dist/handsontable.full.min.css" in styles in angular.json which caused this.